# The difference between (x^y) and !(!(x^y))

Tags: c, boolean, bitwise-operators, negation

I am a new computer science undergrad. For my assignment I need to implement `isNotEqual(int x, int y)` function in C by just using bitwise operators. This function will return false if x and y are equal, true otherwise. I have tried to just use `x ^ y`, but it couldn't pass all the test cases. My assumption was if only x and y are equal, it will return as a 0, and if they are not equal, it will return as a non-zero integer. In our first lessons, we learned that C returns non-zero values as true. To solve this problem I tried to use `!(!(x ^ y))` and it worked. I can see the difference between my 2 solutions. For the second one, all the bits are converted to '1' but I don't understand why the simpler first solution doesn't work. Can someone explain why my first solution couldn't pass all the tests?

I tried:

```
int isNotEqual(int x, int y){
    return x^y;
}
```

But the correct solution was:

```
int isNotEqual(int x, int y){
    return !(!(x^y));
}
```

Comment: Why do you say this function is not working? `isNotEqual` returns 0 when they are equal and something other than 0 when they are not equal. Isn't that what it was supposed to do?

Comment: `!!` will force the value to be 0/1 (anything nonzero becomes 1). Presumably at least one of the tests was testing for values that are not 0 or 1? Hard to say for sure without seeing the tests.

Comment: You say that non-zero values are `true`, but note that `int i = 3; bool b = true; if(i == b) puts("true");` does not output anything. You could easily implement both function and find values yourself where one gives the wrong value.

Comment: If there was no requirement to return exactly 0 or 1 you should ask for the regrade

Comment: @WeatherVane implicit integer promotions. It is not the correct way of comparing

Comment: @gulpr my point was that the OP hasn't shown what the caller's test is.

Comment: @WeatherVane why would ever be testing against `true`?

Comment: @giusti why was the unnecessary `bool` type added anyway?

Comment: @WeatherVane you can set variables with `true` and `false`. But it's redundant to compare against `true` in any language. If you need `(x == true)` instead of simply `(x)`, why not `(x == true) == true`?

Comment: @giusti I was just making the point that `3` is not `true`, but `if(3)` is.

Comment: I understand, and you are right. But I'm saying that `3` is a truth value and you don't need a truth value to be exactly `1`. Instead of requiring the function to return either `1` or `0`, it is better to avoid comparing against `true`. Comparing against `true` is never necessary (unless for some reason you need to ensure data type, then you are in some language which has operators like `===`; But that's a different story).

Comment: @giusti I don't, but some beginners do. I just thought it worth pointing out to a beginner, without being jumped on.

Comment: How about something like `isNE(100,0) == isNE(10,0)`? Expected true, actual result false. (yes, this is still about the 0/1 result, just trying to justify that requirement)

Comment: A web search on `"isNotEqual" bitwise operators` produces a number of pages that have the same or similar solutions: https://github.com/javaknight1/Manipulating-Bits/blob/master/bits.c They all seem to use the `!!` trick to get _just_ a 0/1 value.

Comment: @giusti unfortunately we don't know the requirements. But it seems the function is required to return `true` or `false`.  Not "something that evaluates to a trueish value when used in a condition.". Therefore any unit test for such a function clearly must test for `== true`. Otherwise it would do an extremely poor job. You test for the spec. And without knowing that spec, you cannot rely on such a claim as "don't need a truth value to exactly 1".

Answer (score 2):

You have not shown the text of the assignment. Likely one of these things is true:

- The assignment specifies to return one if `x` and `y` are not equal and zero otherwise. In this case, you need to use `return !! (x^y);` or equivalent.
- The assignment specifies to return non-zero if `x` and `y` are not equal and zero otherwise. In this case, `return x^y;` is sufficient and, if the test program complains, it is improperly written.
- The assignment fails to specify what to return. In this case, the specification is deficient, and you should ask the instructor to complete it.

Answer (score 2):

The difference between `x^y` and `!(!(x^y))` is that when `x` and `y` are unequal, the former might take a wide range of nonzero values, but the latter will evaluate to exactly 1.

Any non-zero value is truthy in C, so your simpler implementation is plausible. It does not match the behavior of the `!=` operator, however, which always evaluates to either 0 or 1, not any other value.  Presumably, then, the latter behavior is what was expected.  If the exercise was not clear about that then it was flawed, and you might have a case for a re-grade.

Answer (score 2):

To answer your specific question: `!(!(x))` will always evaluate to `0` *or* `1`, regardless of the original value of `x`. Whereas `x` evaluates to `x`.

This is because the negation operator `!` converts non-zero values to `0`, and `0` *to `1` always*. As such if `x` above started out as:

- `0`, it'll be `0` -> `1` -> `0`
- Not `0` (`1`, `-1`, `123`), it'll be `x` -> `0` -> `1`

To make it concrete, the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int isNotEqual(int x, int y){
    return !(!(x^y));
}

int isNotEqual2(int x, int y){
    return x^y;
}

int main() {
    printf("isNotEqual(1, 1): %d\n", isNotEqual(1, 1));
    printf("isNotEqual2(1, 1): %d\n", isNotEqual2(1, 1));
    printf("isNotEqual(1, 123): %d\n", isNotEqual(1, 123));
    printf("isNotEqual2(1, 123): %d\n", isNotEqual2(1, 123));
}
```

Prints out:

```
isNotEqual(1, 1): 0
isNotEqual2(1, 1): 0
isNotEqual(1, 123): 1
isNotEqual2(1, 123): 122
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems it is the implementation of tests is incorrect or their requirements are very strict. I can suppose that they compare returned values of the function with exactly `0` and `1`. So if two integers are not equal to each other then the first function can return any non-zero value depending on values of its arguments.

Instead of using the expression `!(!(x^y))` that yileds either 1 or 0 you could just change the declaration of the function by changing its return type from `int` to `_Bool` as for example

```
_Bool isNotEqual(int x, int y){
    return x ^ y;
}
```

From  the C Standard (6.3.1.2 Boolean type)

> 1 When any scalar value is converted to _Bool, the result is 0 if the
> value compares equal to 0; otherwise, the result is 1

Or you could include header `<stdbool.h>` and write

```
#include <stdbool.h>

bool isNotEqual(int x, int y){
    return x ^ y;
}
```

Alternatively instead of using the expression `!(!(x^y))` that is less readable you could also write

```
int isNotEqual(int x, int y){
    return ( x ^ y ) != 0;
}
```

In this case again the function will return either `1` or `0`.

As for the expression `!(!(x^y))` then all what you should know is the following (The C Standard, 6.5.3.3 Unary arithmetic operators)

> 5 The result of the logical negation operator ! is 0 if the value of
> its operand compares unequal to 0, 1 if the value of its operand
> compares equal to 0. The result has type int. The expression !E is
> equivalent to (0==E).

So if the sub-exoression `x ^ y` yields `0` then the subexpression `!( x ^ y )` yields `1` and using one more the negation operator like `!( !( x ^ y ) )` you will get again `0` if initially `z ^ y` yields `0`.